# Bootstrap toggle menu with google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a template with Bootstrap. Firstly, I added two navbar. I used position is fixed. I want to use toogle menu with Detail, List and Map links. Later I created three div elements. First element have col-md-2 class. Second element have col-md-4 class. Third element have col-md-6 class. When the page is loaded the third element default class have col-md-12. Detail is clicked the map class should be col-md-10 and first div should be visible. Later List is clicked if first div is not visible List should be visible and map should be col-md-8. When the first div is visible and second div is clicked. First div should be col-md-2. Second div should be col-md-4 and map should be col-md-6. How can I solve? Also map didnt work on https://jsfiddle.net. Fiddle link is https://jsfiddle.net/sgq0oqeb/5/ .

**HTML code**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" style="border-bottom:1px solid #cdcdcd; min-height:40px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Place</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default"style="margin-top:50px; margin-bottom:0px; background-color:#cafd96; border:0 !important; height:40px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">                  
                <li><a id="menu-toggle">Detail</a></li>
                <li><a id="menu-toggle2">List</a></li>
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Map</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-md-2 hidden" style="border:1px solid black" id="detail">
        <div class="container-fullwidth">
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
                    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                        <li class="sidebar-brand">
                            <a href="#">
                                Start Bootstrap
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Shortcuts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Overview</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Events</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Services</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Contact</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div id="page-content-wrapper">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>              
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 hidden" id="list">
    Second Div
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0px;" id="harita">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default"style=" margin-bottom:0px; border-radius:0px; background-color:#cdcdcd">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                    <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>  
        <div id="map"></div>            
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" style="z-index:1 !important; background-color:#cdcdcd">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <!--<li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>-->

            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

**Javascript code**

```
      var map;
        var marker;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: {
                    lat: 38.72837591823979,
                    lng: 35.13427734375
                },
                zoom: 7,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);  
        }; 
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: The problem you are encountering is you don't quite understand with Bootstrap Grid System. So in my opinion, you have to learn it first.

Comment: Where is Google Map js and css in your fiddle code?